# GovData.de license zero-2-0

Tags: government, licensing, inspire

Does this license have to be passed on (I don't have the technical term), if the licensed data is used or passed on?

https://www.govdata.de/dl-de/zero-2-0

> Data licence Germany - Zero - Version 2.0
>
> Any use is permitted without restrictions or conditions.
>
> The data and meta-data provided may, for commercial and non-commercial
>   use, in particular
>
> 1. be copied, printed, presented, altered, processed and transmitted to third parties;
> 2. be merged with own data and with the data of others and be combined to form new and independent datasets;
> 3. be integrated in internal and external business processes, products and applications in public and non-public electronic
>      networks.

(Example data: search for zero-2-0 on http://www.geodatenkatalog.de)

Comment: I'm also curious about this but more to do specifically with Canada's [Open Government License](https://open.canada.ca/en/open-government-licence-canada)